# Inline style won't overwrite

Tags: html, css, wordpress, overflow, inline

Pretty new to this coding stuff so forgive the ignorance :)

I'm trying to remove some inline styling from this Wordpress theme which I understand overwrites any external CSS files.

When I 'inspect element' I get the following, and changing `hidden` to `visible` on the right does work. But usually it would say like `style.css:202` or whatever line of the CSS I need to change and that's how I usually do it. This time though obviously it says `element.style {` and I can see that `style="overflow: hidden;` on the left hand side (highlighted).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu9XT.jpg

**How would I go about essentially making that overflow visible?**

I've added the following custom css but it just crosses out the overflow and doesn't change anything:

```
.slides_container[style] {overflow:visible !important;}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try with overflow:auto;

Answer (score 1):

For me `overflow:auto!important` and `overflow:visible!important` both working nicely.
See live here: http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/h7JmT/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Setting .slides_container[style]  overflow:auto !important;} has worked but it is adding scrollbars to images which shouln't need them. The area is 600x480, as are the images. I think what it's doing is adding scrollbars and then scrolling to reveal the 10px or so that the scrollbars are blocking.

Comment: Can't see anything at given Link. overflow:auto; is actually supposed to add scrollbar, that's why it's used.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is a javascript which is adding these styles on document load. And I believe this is some kind of slider where usually the overflow is hidden. If you need a slider where overflow is visible, then select your desired slider and use it. Make sure you remove the present slider before doing so.

putting

```
overflow: visible !important
```

will allow you to give preference over styles inheriting from other style sources. But will not stop a javascript changing the styles.

I believe this one below created by roXon will give you some idea of overflow : visible sliders
http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tMxp5/1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding the overflow rule to the specific slider did the trick but I still don't know how to add this into the actual theme rather than just the temporary changes in the Chrome 'inspect element' bit.

Setting .slides_container[style] overflow:auto !important;} in my custom CSS has worked but it is adding scrollbars to images which shouln't need them. The area is 600x480, as are the images. I think what it's doing is adding scrollbars and then scrolling to reveal the 10px or so that the scrollbars are blocking. Any ideas?

See here http://www.acjjphotography.com/#/sureguard

Comment: when you are editing it with inspect element, you are actually changing the styles which are set by javascript on document load. Javascript usually sets styles as style attributes (or otherwise called as element styles). using overflow : auto will not give you the control you need. This may act differently in different browsers. My advice is to either look at the javascript plugin and change the code there (a bit complex method) or change the plugin (easy way and you have lots of sliders available). put some code in fiddle may be, I ll tweak it if you wish